# Are adult movies (as far as industry, actors, etc... are concerned) on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I asked the question in a way that I think should avoid offending anyone (e.g. "no links to adult sites or names of porn movies in answers, please").

[Who was the first actor/actress who made the move from Adult to Non-Adult movies full time?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1067/who-was-the-first-actor-actress-who-made-the-move-from-porn-to-non-porn-movies-f)

However, I'm worried if even having adult movies theme would make this off-topic?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As long as everything is kept scientific and tasteful a la [**the failed sexuality.SE site**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3303/sexuality)  Then I do not forsee a problem.  If things get out of hand though..well I think that's obvious.

Comment: I agree - I see no reason why that question could not be asked

Comment: Is there some blog post explaining why SexualitySE failed? Was it merely low Area51 low stats or some intrinsic problem? (I didn't participate, but was greatly interested in its success, as many of Skeptics SE questions could be better answered there)

Comment: Not entirely sure why, I heard something about the numbers, but then again their numbers aren't too far off from ours at the moment as well as it not even being let out of private beta.

Comment: @DVK Low traffic and low quality. There was a meta post explaining that (visible to anyone through the API for a few days, it's gone now).

Comment: The majority of the crowd went into the site with a programmer/SO/tech/referencesnoopinions mindset putting off actual experts that had experience but no literature to back up their claims. The main misconception was that subjectivity was not allowed thus putting a stop too many subjective yet informative questions. Counsellors and experts in this field don't have literature and scientific backing to much of their knowledge but such is life when 61.8% of your committers are active on SO.

Answer (score 10):

I don't have a problem with questions about adult movies being on topic per se as long as the question is serious and tasteful.

We should not let this user derail the site by bombarding it with a series of badly worded and frankly not that interesting questions, but I don't see why adult movies should be made off topic because of one unregistered user.

Another reason for not doing this is that the boundary between adult content and mainstream is somewhat vague - there is a continuous spectrum, and defining where the allowable boundary is would be difficult.

Banning adult content remains something we can apply should this get out of hand - frankly apart from this one user, no-one seems that interested in asking such questions anyway.

Answer (score 9):

There is nothing that prevents one from talking about it but you may risk trying to keep a handle on controlling the links for adult questions when the traffic increases.

As stated in Stack Exchange Content Policy

> Sexually Explicit Material. Accounts that use Stack Exchange to post sexually explicit or pornographic material, or links to it, will be suspended.

Which I imagine would apply to all content. There is nothing that prevents a change in the policy but this is currently not the case as the only site so far violating this policy has been closed so we will never know for sure.

In addition as [stated by Jeff here](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364/are-questions-about-adult-web-apps-on-or-off-topic),

> No, I don't think we want this, as it would cause us to get globally banned from web filtering software

So, as long as there is no links to sexually explicit material you should be good. I would suggest adding the [adult-movies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adult-movies) tag on your favorites tag list to keep an eye on it and ensure proper policy is maintained.

Answer (score 3):

I think there should not be any problems as long as it involves adding to the understanding or appreciation of the title. The line between Rated-R and MA gets small sometimes

Some examples

- Swordfish
- Monster's Ball
- American Pie
- Original Sin
- American Psycho
- Shoot ‘Em Up

Then again, from a different side can one source adult movies that actually produce content beyond the banal sexual desire? Not sure. You would more likely find some extent to an appreciation in a softcore like Emmanuelle. Also on further inspection seeing that identify-this is one of the highest used tags, *would it be okay for one to post an identify-this-adult-movie ?* Again not sure, the more content to the question the easier for it to get an answer but at the same time swaying towards the path of explicit content.

The most popular adult movies may not actually show appreciation past sexual fantasy (e.g. Night in Paris) so I think for the upkeep of keeping the aim of MTV to be about appreciation of film and not sexual desires then either range of movies that fall under this will need to be highly monitored or adult movies should be **off-topic**

Comment: Definitely agree though I think for now we should err on the side of monitoring and then squashing, should it become a problem.

Answer (score 2):

I still defer to my argument [**made earlier**](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263/are-adult-movies-as-far-as-industry-actors-etc-are-concerned-on-topic)

Both those questions are from an unreg'd user, which is why us mods should **follow** those tags so that we can catch them quick.  The first one he posted, I turned into a salvageable question, the second is just blatantly off-topic along the lines of "how does one become an actor" its the same question, just because it is made for the adult industry itself, doesn't mean we should punish it as a whole.

Until I see a question that blatantly shows that they are useless in general, I say allow them.  As long as they're tasteful and ok by the devs/owners/SE Team, I see no issue.

Answer (score 2):

I voted to close the two useless questions asked today, but only because one was asking for a list, and the other was just silly (the condom question).
This got me thinking about the whole situation, and I agree with your conclusions - monitoring and squashing seems to be the way to go.

I don't think there should be any sort of censorship imposed on the types of films that are represented here, although there is certainly a distinction between the latest Kardashian sex tape and Busty Cops III, just as long as the question still falls within the guidelines of the site.

If you start to make adult films off-topic, then the line becomes blurred very quickly - where should we place The Brown Bunny, Last Tango in Paris, 9 1/2 Weeks, etc etc ?

So I say a film is a film is a film, and if the question fits the FAQ, it has a place on the site.