# Should adult movies really be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are adult movies (as far as industry, actors, etc… are concerned) on topic?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263/are-adult-movies-as-far-as-industry-actors-etc-are-concerned-on-topic)

We've gotten two posts about adult movies in the last 24 hours.  Do we **really** want questions about adult movies to be on-topic?

By adult, I mean videos that are recorded and viewed for....

Honestly, it's not the prude in me that doesn't want to see them, but the fact that I can't envision any quality questions coming out of this.  I also don't think our main viewers would want to see these types of questions mixed in with their regular movie and tv questions.

Thoughts?